# SQL qn:- comparing data in rows

Tags: sql, compare

i would like to compare numeric data in rows. for eg, i have a table that has a column as such:-

```
Number
======
 1.88
 9.99
 8.76
 9.88
```

I want to compare 2nd value, 3rd value, 4th value to the 1st value. And then 3rd, 4th value to the 2nd. then 4th to 3rd.

How can i construct an sql to do this?

Comment: i tried transposing the values, then i wanted to do a case statement to compare each and every value. but this will be massive, as i have at least 100 over values. 

i also tried inner joining the table with the same number column, and then subtract column1 and column2 to compare which value is greater. but logic doesnt work exactly as the next comparison omits the preceeding value. ie. after comparing 2nd, 3rd, 4th with 1st value. next comparison is 3rd & 4th with 2nd. 

any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have some way of assigning sequence numbers to the rows.

Consider the following table:

```
seq  number
---  ------
  1    1.88
  2    9.99
  3    8.76
  4    9.88
```

created with:

```
drop table a;
commit;
create table a (seq integer,num float);                                     
insert into a (seq,num) values (1,1.88);
insert into a (seq,num) values (2,9.99);
insert into a (seq,num) values (3,8.76);
insert into a (seq,num) values (4,9.88);
commit;
```

You can then execute:

```
select
    ta.seq as aseq,
    tb.seq as bseq,
    ta.num as anum,
    tb.num as bnum,
    ta.num - tb.num as diff
from a ta, a tb
where tb.seq > ta.seq;
```

which will give you:

```
aseq  bseq  anum  bnum   diff
----  ----  ----  ----  -----
   1     2  1.88  9.99  -8.11
   1     3  1.88  8.76  -6.88
   1     4  1.88  9.88  -8.00
   2     3  9.99  8.76   1.23
   2     4  9.99  9.88   0.11
   3     4  8.76  9.88  -1.12
```

Comment: thank you so much. you guys are the best. i think i should be able to work it out from here onwards. thanks again. i really appreciate all the help.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure of the utility of this but maybe that is what you are looking for...
An easier way to compare values is to use the ORDER BY clause.

I took the liberty of adding an id column to the table which I call tblTst.  This is convenient to select some specific values (see the WHERE id in (...) clause), and also it is used to only avoid duplicates in the cross product. To compare the whole table, simply omit the WHERE clause. The join condition can be changed to strictly less than (<) to prevent comparing values with themselves  (was just convenient to test my '=')

With 100 values in the table the bottom (or top) triangle of the matrix will include 5,000 comparisons.  (again, I'm puzzled as to how this can be useful or fun...)

```
select T1.value AS Operand1,
     CASE WHEN T1.Value < T2.Value THEN '<'
          WHEN T1.Value = T2.Value Then '='
          ELSE '>'
     END AS Comp,
     T2.Value AS Operand2
FROM tblTst T1
JOIN tblTst T2 ON T1.id <= T2.id
WHERE T1.id in (1,2,3,4)

Sample output     
Operand1 Comp  Operand2
1.88    =   1.88
1.88    <   9.99
1.88    <   8.76
1.88    <   9.88
9.99    =   9.99
9.99    >   8.76
9.99    >   9.88
8.76    =   8.76
8.76    <   9.88
9.88    =   9.88
```

Comment: hi pax, 

i tried your sql, it works nicely. i need a case statement to compare the difference, like this:- 

value1 > value2 --> +1
value1 < value2 --> -1
value1=value2 --> 0

then i need to add all the +1, -1 (numbers)...

mjv, i've not tried yours, i am trying to think how to put in the sequence numbering automatically. 

any ideas?

Comment: @rayhan: if the table is small enough -which I think it is- you may just insert all its row in a new table with the same schema plus an extra column with an auto-incremented primary key.  Pax and my solution are essentially the same, except for the case statement.  If you replace the comparison signs (<=> by -1, 0 and +1, either as number values or as striings, you should get what you need.  You can also copy the CASE statement to Pax' query.  Another trick would be to use SIGN(ta.num -tb.num) insted of just the difference.

Answer (score 0):

Just simplifying @paxdiablo's work into t-sql parlance for my understanding:

```
declare @t table 
(
    id integer identity (1, 1)
)
-- sample data
insert @t default values
insert @t default values
insert @t default values
insert @t default values

select
    a.id as a_id,
    b.id as b_id
from 
    @t as a 
cross join 
    @t as b
where 
    a.id < b.id
order by
    1, 2
```

gives

```
a_id        b_id
----------- -----------
1           2
1           3
1           4
2           3
2           4
3           4

(6 row(s) affected)
```